# Spring: Idiomatic way to add query parameters

Tags: java, spring, url

What's an idiomatic way in Spring to add additional query parameters to a given URL? The URL might already contain query parameters or a fragment. Of course, the parameter values must be properly encoded.

*Idiomatic* means that I'm looking for concise code without importing any additional libraries beyond a typical Spring Boot installation.

The method should have this signature:

```
/**
 Add additional query parameters to the specified URL.

 @param url the URL
 @param params map with additional query parameters (parameter name/value pairs)
 @return the new URL
 */
String addQueryParameters(String url, Map<String, String> params);
```

Given these additional parameters:

```
price: €25
name: Réne e Suzanne
config: {"f1":34,"f2":"&?"}
```

and these URLs:

```
http://www.app.com/one%20two/
http://www.berry.nz/one/two?return=%7B%22abc%22%3A%22%25%5E%3F%22%7D
http://www.soil.au:8080/one/two#section-2
```

the expected outcome should be:

```
http://www.app.com/one%20two/?price=%E2%82%AC25&name=R%C3%A9ne+e+Suzanne&config=%7B%22f1%22%3A34%2C%22f2%22%3A%22%26%3F%22%7D
http://www.berry.nz/one/two?return=%7B%22abc%22%3A%22%25%5E%3F%22%7D&price=%E2%82%AC25&name=R%C3%A9ne+e+Suzanne&config=%7B%22f1%22%3A34%2C%22f2%22%3A%22%26%3F%22%7D
http://www.soil.au:8080/one/two?price=%E2%82%AC25&name=R%C3%A9ne+e+Suzanne&config=%7B%22f1%22%3A34%2C%22f2%22%3A%22%26%3F%22%7D#section-2
```

BTW: It's for serious software (no homework). I tried to solve it with `UriComponentsBuilder` and failed... :-(

**Update**

The problem with `UriComponentsBuilder` is that it cannot undo the percent encoding of the query parameters. I then ended up with a mixture of encoded and unencoded parameters with two outs: the existing parameters were incorrectly double encoded or the additional parameters were not encoded at all.

Comment: Can you provide some details of what you've tried that didn't work?

Comment: @armandino See my update

Comment: @Codo: I would argue that it is a serious software, because it expects that JSON object is passed via GET. If you can influence the service API, try to avoid that and either split JSON into separate request parameters or, if you want to keep JSON, use other method instead of GET. **Bonus:** If you use other method e.g. POST, you will not have to care about escaping of special chars.

Comment: I would agree. Unfortunately, I cannot change it. It has been baked into the OpenID Connect standard (see ['claims' request parameter](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ClaimsParameter)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URLs are a bit difficult to encode as different encoding types are mixed. For instance, spaces in the URL are encoded as `%20` while the spaces in query parameters are encoded as `+`. Therefore, I have created a method `encodeUtf8` to separately encode the query parameters:

```java
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class SomeTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://www.app.com/one%20two/")
                .queryParam("price", encodeUtf8("€25"))
                .queryParam("name", encodeUtf8("Réne e Suzanne"))
                .queryParam("config", encodeUtf8("{\"f1\":34,\"f2\":\"&?\"}"))
                .build()
                .toUriString();

        assertThat(url).isEqualTo("http://www.app.com/one%20two/?price=%E2%82%AC25&name=R%C3%A9ne+e+Suzanne&config=%7B%22f1%22%3A34%2C%22f2%22%3A%22%26%3F%22%7D");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://www.berry.nz/one/two?return=%7B%22abc%22%3A%22%25%5E%3F%22%7D")
                .queryParam("price", encodeUtf8("€25"))
                .queryParam("name", encodeUtf8("Réne e Suzanne"))
                .queryParam("config", encodeUtf8("{\"f1\":34,\"f2\":\"&?\"}"))
                .build()
                .toUriString();

        assertThat(url).isEqualTo("http://www.berry.nz/one/two?return=%7B%22abc%22%3A%22%25%5E%3F%22%7D&price=%E2%82%AC25&name=R%C3%A9ne+e+Suzanne&config=%7B%22f1%22%3A34%2C%22f2%22%3A%22%26%3F%22%7D");
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() throws Exception {
        String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://www.soil.au:8080/one/two#section-2")
                .queryParam("price", encodeUtf8("€25"))
                .queryParam("name", encodeUtf8("Réne e Suzanne"))
                .queryParam("config", encodeUtf8("{\"f1\":34,\"f2\":\"&?\"}"))
                .build()
                .toUriString();

        assertThat(url).isEqualTo("http://www.soil.au:8080/one/two?price=%E2%82%AC25&name=R%C3%A9ne+e+Suzanne&config=%7B%22f1%22%3A34%2C%22f2%22%3A%22%26%3F%22%7D#section-2");
    }

    private static String encodeUtf8(String val) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return URLEncoder.encode(val, "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So your approach is to not let `UriComponentsBuilder` encode anything... I'll give it a try.

Comment: Correct. Furthermore, the [UriComponentsBuilder#queryParam](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html#queryParam-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) documentation mentions: `Note: encoding, if applied, will only encode characters that are illegal in a query parameter name or value such as = or &`. As the query parameters in your URLs require encoding, I have used the URLEncoder.

Comment: It works. And fortunately the handling of spaces is correct as well. But `UriComponentsBuilder` would be able to encode the query parameters as it (and `UriComponents`) support three encodings: *none*, *template* and *full*. Which one is applied depends on whether you call `builder.encode().build()` or `builder.build().encode()` or `builder.build(false)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it turns out that `URLEncoder` is far more eager in escaping characters than `UriComponentsBuilder`. It's not incorrect but unecessary. Unfortunately, the escaping methods of `UriComponentsBuilder` (or rather `HierarchicalUriComponents`) aren't publicly accessible.